# Selenium driver throws error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, linux, selenium, ubuntu-18.04

I am porting my code over from Windows to Ubuntu, I went ahead and installed java, and all the drivers, and built my jar file. While executing it, I am getting this error. I downloaded the Linux 64bit Chrome Driver for this.

```
Feb 01, 2021 12:20:51 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}) on port 21398
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxxxxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0', java.version: '11.0.9.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5567a65a12b9 <unknown>

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:147)
        at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

The error seems to be starting from my jars main class line 17, which is this line.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

Here is my entire code, that I am trying to execute.

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

```
public class Main {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=Profile 1");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `--disable-dev-shm-usage` as an argument seems to solve the issue.

```
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```